# To add double quotes to the values in a columns wherever the values have quotes within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with some columns containing values with quotes. So, as per my requirement, I need to add double quotes to all such values in a columns.

Example data:-

```
Id person city
1  'john' "Los Angeles"
2  'otis' "Mumbai"
3  'Maeve' "Kerala"
```

So, assume my data in a dataframe will be like this and I need to add double quotes to the values in **person** column and as well as **city** column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you want to ask how to do it, well, what have you already tried? And what output do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your dataframe :

```
  person city
0      A    C
1      B    D
```

Simply add double quote to the entire column (before and after the value)

```
df["person"] = '"' + df["person"] + '"'
df["city"] = '"' + df["city"] + '"'
```

Result :

```
  person city
0    "A"  "C"
1    "B"  "D"
```

Comment: What if we have more number of columns like this and what if we don't know what all columns are like this?